# Сравнение отрисовки UserControl и Window при перемещении

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня появилась потребность перетаскивания `UserContol` по родительскому `Grid`'y. Заметил что при перетаскивании контрола появляется задержка визуализации, не смотря на то что `Margin` у `UserControl` уже присвоен окончательный, сам контрол еще не закончил движение.

Я решил проверить тот же принцип работы но уже на `Window`. Там пример работает идеально и отклонение даже если и есть то +-1px.

Синий круг это UserControl который находится на сером Grid

Красный круг это отдельное окно которое перемещается с помощью `this.DragMove()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться с этой проблемой, пожалуйста! [Архив с самим проектом](https://m.mega.dp.ua/YG7AZB85m)

Answer (score 0):

Я упростил код XAML контрола UserControl1, изменил механизм пересчёта его положения при перемещении - и у меня на ПК при перемещении контрола и окна почти не заметно разницы.
UserContol.xaml.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControl1 : Grid
{
    Point _startPoint;
    Vector _startTransform;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Сохраняем начальные значения до того как захватываем мышь
        _startPoint = e.GetPosition(Parent as Window);
        _startTransform = new Vector(controlTranslateTransform.X, controlTranslateTransform.Y);
        CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {            
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            Vector offset = Point.Subtract
                (e.GetPosition(Parent as Window), _startPoint);

            controlTranslateTransform.X = (_startTransform + offset).X;
            controlTranslateTransform.Y = (_startTransform + offset).Y;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl.xaml:

```
<Grid
    x:Class="WpfApp3.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp"
    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="controlTranslateTransform"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"/>
    <Label
        Content="U"
        FontSize="40"        
        FontWeight="Bold"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="LightPink"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переделанный проект выложил тут (VS 2019): https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6mBA/dV2GMwY3o

Comment: Попробовал запустить оба проекта и проверить действительно ли другой метод расчета перемещения влияет на перетаскивание элементов. Лично у меня на ПК я не вижу отличий между моим проектом и вашим. На обоих проектах есть ощутимая разница между перетаскиванием Window и UserControl. 


Прошу обратить внимание на то что параметр UserControl.Margin обновляется мгновенно( Я проверил это методом присваивания положения Window в функции где происходит пересчет положения UserControl.) Выходит что Window  идет ровно за мышкой а UserControl отстает не смотря на то что Margin у них идентичный.

Comment: Мне кажется это результат полной перерисовки всего родительского элемента

Comment: У меня на компьютере разница есть (проц. I7-6500U, видео GTX 950M). Видимо, "железо" получше. Вполне возможно такое, что при полном перетаскивании окна его отображение не пересчитывается, а берётся откуда-то из кэша и помещается в новое место экрана. А в случае перемещения контрола система фиксирует изменение окна и потому его отрисовка просчитывается заново. И чем проще эта отрисовка реализована, тем быстрее она происходит. Поэтому в моём варианте перетаскивание быстрее работает (по крайней мере, у меня).

Comment: Видимо вы не смотрели мой проект так как у нас идентичные варианты расчета положения окна =). По поводу железа... I5 7400 1060 GPU.

Comment: Я не про расчёты положения, а про код контрола, в том числе и xaml-разметку. Сравните Вашу и мою. Какая из них проще? Какую из них компьютер быстрее обработает?

Comment: Ну вы же не думаете что вся суть приложения перетаскивание кружков? В готовом проекте могу присутствовать сотни контролов, стили, анимации и тд. и в итоге Window будет перемещаться плавно и быстро а UserControl в том же духе тормозить с прорисовкой

Comment: Видимо да, так и будет. И есть подозрение, что никак на это не повлиять, кроме как оптимизиацией кода контрола и родительского окна. По крайней мере, мне ничего другого в голову не приходит. Может быть, кто-то ещё подключится и посоветует что-то толковое на этот счёт.

Comment: Не первый день занимаюсь этим вопросом. Пока что безуспешно( Как будут ощутимые результаты обязательно отпишу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96664/discussion-between---and-dmitriy-zagorulkin).